# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client cannot connect using Windows authentication

Tags: oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

We are unable to connect to Oracle 19c using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client and windows authentication. Regular .NET 4.0 apps are able to connect but .NET Core apps are not able to connect (both are using managed driver).

Below is the code we're using:

```
 var connString = @"User ID=/;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=test)(PORT=2501))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test)));";
            using (var comm = new OracleCommand("SELECT 'It Works' FROM DUAL", new OracleConnection(connString)))
            {
                comm.Connection.Open();
                return comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
```

sqlnet.ora is setup properly

Comment: Maybe this one https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/18.3/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-51D1ADDB-D6B2-44A8-858F-336BE63C9064

Comment: what about that one????

Comment: The document lists some limitations of the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver. They may apply in your case. Apart from that: "not able to connect" is not a useful error message, what error do you get?

Comment: So, whats the error you get?